# select the second longest time from mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know the second longest time by topic using the sql query below but it resulted in error:

```
SELECT h.topic AS Help_Topic, MAX(TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , t.created, t.closed )) as SecondMax
FROM ost_ticket t, ost_help_topic h
WHERE t.topic_id = h.topic_id
AND t.status =  'Closed'
AND t.dept_id =  '1'
AND t.created >=  '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , t.created, t.closed ) < SecondMax 
GROUP BY t.topic_id
ORDER BY Closed DESC");
```

I suspect the link " AND TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , t.created, t.closed ) < SecondMax " is the culprit but I am not sure.

The database table:

h.topic | created              | closed

kid     | 2014-01-01 00:05:00  | 2014-01-02 00:06:00

kid     | 2014-01-01 00:05:00  | 2014-01-02 00:07:00

kid     | 2014-01-01 00:05:00  | 2014-01-02 00:08:00

adult   | 2014-01-01 00:05:00  | 2014-01-02 00:07:00

adult   | 2014-01-01 00:05:00  | 2014-01-02 00:10:00

adult   | 2014-01-01 00:05:00  | 2014-01-02 00:14:00

The desired result is

Help_topic | SecondMax

kid        | 2

adult      | 5

Thanks

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: You could maybe try a `TOP 2` approach? [See Here for TOP documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-top-clause.htm)

Comment: "it resulted in error" - well, what was the error message?

Comment: i have added the desired result.another thing, how do i make standard deviation using the filtered result? when i add another colum using "STD(TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , t.created, t.closed )) as Std_Resolution", the result still includes the longest time for calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have definitely identified the culprit.  You cannot reference a column alias `SecondMax` in the `where` clause.

If you want the second longest times subject to these conditions, I would go for the `group_concat()` approach.  You concatenate the strings durations together and then extract the second from them:

```
SELECT h.topic AS Help_Topic,
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t.created, t.closed )
                                                    order by TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t.created, t.closed) desc
                                                   ), ',', 2
                                       ), ',', -1
                      ) as SecondMax
FROM ost_ticket t join
     ost_help_topic h
     on t.topic_id = h.topic_id
WHERE t.status =  'Closed' AND t.dept_id =  '1' AND t.created >=  '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY t.topic_id;
```

I also changed the `join` to use proper explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: thanks.how do i make standard deviation using the filtered result? when i add another colum using STD(TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE , t.created, t.closed )) as Std_Resolution, the result still includes the longest time for calculation

Comment: That's another question